# How to write JUnit 5 test cases for the following code?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit5, springmockito

This is the method to write the JUnit test cases for

```
public List<LoanApiCallEntity> getAllApiCallDetails() {

    return apiCallDetailsRepository.findAll();
}
```

Inside the LoanApiCallEntity class these are the following:

```
public class LoanApiCallEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "loan_api_call_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int apiCallId;
    
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name="call_timestamp", nullable=false, updatable=false)
    private Timestamp callDateTime;
    
    @Column(name = "request_url")
    private String requestURL;
    
    @Column(name="request_parameters")
    private String requestParameters;
    
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
    
    @Column(name = "response_status")
    private String responseStatus;

}
```

This is the test case I have tried, but it shows an error:

```
@MockBean ApiCallDetailsServiceImpl apiCallDetailsService;

@Test public void apiCallDetailsServiceImpltest() {

 LoanApiCallEntity entity = new LoanApiCallEntity();

    entity.setApiCallId(1);

    Mockito.doReturn(entity).when(this.apiCallDetailsService).getAllApiCallDetails();

    Assertions.assertEquals(entity.getApiCallId(),1);

}
```

The error shown while running the project (`mvn test`) is - LoanApiCallEntity cannot be returned by getAllApiCallDetails().

Comment: Can you update your question with the full test class and error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getAllApiCallDetails() returns a list of objects so you need to provide a list as a mock value in the doReturn function call.

Comment: can you please tell me how to do a mock list

Comment: `Mockito.doReturn(List.of(entity)).when(this.apiCallDetailsService).getAllApiCallDetails();`